How to use the loop to produce the rows in tabularray with latex3
I want to use the for-loop in tabularray environment tblr with \int_step_inline:nn, but get stuck by the \\? How to change the code to achieve it?
Here below is the MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_const:Nn \c_days_clist { Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday }

What~I~want~with~\LaTeX{}3~but~failed.. \par
\begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines}
    Column \\
    \clist_item:Nn \c_days_clist { 1 } \\
    Column \\
    \clist_item:Nn \c_days_clist { 2 } \\
    Column \\
    \clist_item:Nn \c_days_clist { 3 } \\
    Column \\
    \clist_item:Nn \c_days_clist { 4 } \\
    Column \\
\end{tblr}

% \begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines}
%     \int_step_inline:nn {5}{
%         Column \\
%         \clist_item:Nn \c_days_clist { #1 } 
%         \int_compare:nTF{#1=5}{}{\\}
%     }
% \end{tblr}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}

What I want is to achieve it with LaTeX3 in tabularray to produce rows in a pattern as below.


Thanks to my friend ljguo's sincere and quick response, I get another solution:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_const:Nn \c_days_clist { Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday }

What~I~want~with~\LaTeX{}3~but~failed.. \par
\begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines,c}
    Column \\
    \clist_item:Nn \c_days_clist { 1 } \\
    Column \\
    \clist_item:Nn \c_days_clist { 2 } \\
    Column \\
    \clist_item:Nn \c_days_clist { 3 } \\
    Column \\
    \clist_item:Nn \c_days_clist { 4 } \\
    Column \\
    \clist_item:Nn \c_days_clist { 5 }
\end{tblr}

\par
\vspace*{2em}

\def\mycontent{}
\int_step_inline:nn {5}{
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\mycontent\expandafter{
        \mycontent
        Column \\
        \clist_item:Nn \c_days_clist { #1 }
    }
    \int_compare:nTF{#1=5}{}{
        \expandafter\def\expandafter\mycontent\expandafter{\mycontent\\}
    }
}
\begin{tblr}[expand=\mycontent]{hlines,vlines,c}
    \mycontent
\end{tblr}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}



see 3.2.3 Expand Macros First in the documentation.

I have read the documentation you mention above, but what confused me  is that should I make the l3 command \clist_item:Nn and \int_compare:nTF expandable with parameter type f? I am not familar with the expansion in LaTeX3.

Sorry, it cannot work, because tblr absorbs the whole environment's body without any expansion and uses \\ and & for doing its workings. No assignment can be performed at this level.

Thanks to youe explanation, I actually found in the docs of tabularray that it works with \\ and &.

you don't need the special case handling if you want the Friday printed, too ;).

Yes, the spacial case control is unnecessary in the mwe, I forgot that. thank uuuu!

Using Ulrike Fischer's hint ...
Do you want something like this?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_const:Nn \c_days_clist { Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday }

What~I~want~with~\LaTeX{}3~but~failed.. \par
\begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines}
  Column \\
  \clist_item:Nn \c_days_clist { 1 } \\
  Column \\
  \clist_item:Nn \c_days_clist { 2 } \\
  Column \\
  \clist_item:Nn \c_days_clist { 3 } \\
  Column \\
  \clist_item:Nn \c_days_clist { 4 } \\
  Column \\
\end{tblr}

% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728458/
\tl_new:N \l_explorer_tblr_spec_tl
\cs_new:Npn \__explorer_tblr_gen:n #1
{
  Column \\
  \int_compare:nTF{#1=5}{}
  {
    \clist_item:Nn \c_days_clist { #1 } \\
  }
}
\tl_set:Ne \l_explorer_tblr_spec_tl
{
  \int_step_function:nN {5} \__explorer_tblr_gen:n
}
\SetTblrOuter{expand=\l_explorer_tblr_spec_tl}
\begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines}
  \l_explorer_tblr_spec_tl
\end{tblr}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}

This produces the same output for the explicitly specified and iterated cases:


Yes! But I found that there is no need to strip the last \\ for the last one( a little problem with my mwe). My frriend provide another method with primitive \expandafter to do the same thing(I will append to the last of the question) Thanks a lot!
